# Initialize an int in a struct for shared memory

Tags: c

I have an int that keeps track of words in a queue, but I am working with shared memory that should persist across multiple executions. Therefore, I can't simply state

```
int words = 0;
```

as a global variable because it will be overwritten each time I run the program. My struct currently looks like this

```
typedef struct {
  /* List of words stored in the FIFO. */
  Word list[ MAX_WORDS ];
  int words;

} FIFO;
```

I only need to initialize 'words' to 0 for the first run, and after that the value should persist through shared memory, but I'm not sure how to do this without it being reset to 0 each run.

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: To people who vote to close - consider commenting why do you think the question is unclear. It's going to be hard for the asking person to fix the question otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new shared memory area, it's initialised to zeros automatically. That's the case for both `shmget` on Linux and `CreateFileMapping` on Windows. Likely the same on other systems, but you'll have to search in the docs. In practice that means as long as you have proper locking scheme implemented, your app will see only 2 states of the shared memory - either all zeros (you're the first one to open it), or already initialised (another instance opened the shared memory before).

I'm not sure you really want shared memory though. If by "should persist across multiple executions" you mean executions of multiple processes at the same time, then this answer applies. But if you want to run your app, then shut it down, then run it again and have the same FIFO available, then you need to just write it into some file, or an embedded/external database.

Comment: In theory there could be a daemon or something that holds the shared memory open while the other app is stopped and started